# выделить текст между точками/character xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

Доброго времени суток! Пытаюсь выделить текст между двумя точками.

Смастерил бестолковый способ ......:

XML:

```
<con1:node>              
    <con2:node name="SomeName">
        <con2:path>'www.example.com.itsanexample.step1.step2.step3'</con2:path>
    </con2:node>
<con1:node>
```

XSLTv1:

```
<xsl:variable name="Variable1" select="//@name[normalize-space(.) = 'SomeName']/parent::*"/>

                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="//@name[normalize-space(.) = 'SomeName']/parent::*">
                        <xsl:text>Your match:</xsl:text>
                        <xsl:value-of select="substring($Variable1, 35, 5)">
                        </xsl:value-of>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise> <xsl:text>0 matches!</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>

Output:
    Your Match: Step2
```

Проблема заключается в том, что `www.example.com.itsanexample.` всегда статична, a `step1.step2.step3` всегда динамична. Например `step122.step23.step3456`
Неподскажите каким образом возможно выделить текст между 4й и 5й или 6й и 7й точкой, фокусируясь на  characters а не на length?

Answer (score 0):

Помогли на eng. если кому интересно;

Понадобился дополнительный параметр и головокружительный сабстринг.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="Variable1" select="//@name[normalize-space(.) = 'SomeName']/parent::*"/>
    <xsl:param name="string" select="$Variable1"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">

        <result>
            <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($string, 'www.example.com.itsanexample.'), '.'), '.')"/>
        </result>
    </xsl:template>

    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Можно даже обойтись без `<xsl:param name="string" select="$Variable1"/>`, и поменять `<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($string, 'www.example.com.itsanexample.'), '.'), '.')"/>` на `<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(substring-after($Variable1, 'www.example.com.itsanexample.'), '.'), '.')"/>` .